# How do you prevent Subversion merging in stages without saying "resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge"?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to use TortoiseSVN to merge a branch that has been out of the trunk for a very long time. It has been updated with the trunk, but I don't think subversion merge tracking has been working for the entirety of this merge from trunk process. Whenever I merge, it merges only 5-10 revisions (even though it has been specified to merge from 1-HEAD) and then shows a message similar to the following...

> One or more conflicts were produced while merging r6631:6637 into
>   'C:\Work\AllBranches\MyBranchName' --   resolve all conflicts and
>   rerun the merge to apply the remaining   unmerged revisions

The problem is the trunk is currently on r10202. If I need to do this merge process over 500 times, and it takes half a day to confirm all the merge issues it is going to take far too long to complete.

Why is subversion not merging all the revisions, why is it halting halfway through? Is there an option I can pass to allow the full merger to proceed and then allow me to manually confirm merge issues afterward?

Answer (score 3):

If you use tortoiseSVN, I believe there is a option saying solve conflict later, select that one, then it will let you edit conflict after merging.

Comment: Sadly, that made no difference, it is still halting the merge process.

Comment: while I don't know y. Two options here: 1. try this: merge reversion before problem, and then merge after the problem. 2. Try the git, it may provide better merging than svn.

Comment: Any luck to this problem? I also am setting "resolve all later" but it isn't doing it. This seems to be new

Answer (score 0):

The branch has not been reintegrated with a trunk for *way too long*. Subversion tries to apply all the changes made to this branch one by one and encounters conflicts in process. You need to resolve these conflicts to allow the merge to proceed past these conflicts. However, you may want to try the `--ignore-ancestry` option that also disables merge tracking. Don't forget to carefully examine the result of the merge!

> Make sure that you use the latest TortoiseSVN or the **svn.exe**
>   command line client version. Subversion has received numerous
>   improvements since 2011 (the year the OP asked the question).

Modern SVN command line clients provide an interactive conflict *viewer* and *resolver*. Besides other options, the resolver allows you to selectively resolve conflicts or postpone the resolution (meaning to skip conflict resolution of particular conflicts so that you will be able to return to this task later). Read [SVNBook | Resolve Any Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve). Make sure to read the latest available version of SVNBook.